# Configure Php server with ISAP

Tags: php, server, iis

i have hosted my wordpress site in IIS server and its running CGI/FastCGI but I found that CGI/FastCGI is slower than the ISAP.I am working with the performance issue in the site and the site has been live.I tried alot of methods to convert it to ISAP but couldn't.I tried using the windows feature to add the ISAP filter but its not working.Can anyone help how to handle this issue or is there any better tutorials for this ???